# How to load a specific range of input files in Pig

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, glob

I have a set of input files to process using Pig, with the following naming structure:

```
/user/hdp/input/custom/Fold1/train0.txt
/user/hdp/input/custom/Fold1/train1.txt
/user/hdp/input/custom/Fold1/train2.txt
/user/hdp/input/custom/Fold1/train3.txt
...
/user/hdp/input/custom/Fold1/train9.txt
/user/hdp/input/custom/Fold1/train10.txt
/user/hdp/input/custom/Fold1/train11.txt
/user/hdp/input/custom/Fold1/train12.txt
...
```

up to training file 99. I build my Pig script dynamically as a Java String, which I then submit to my cluster. I am looking for a general solution to load the range of train files from *0* up to some number *x*, where I can set this *x* to any java int up to 99.

In a previous version of my solution, that supported values of *x* up to 9, I used the Pig support for globs in the following way:

```
pigString += "TRAIN = LOAD 'user/hdp/input/custom/Fold1/train[0-"+x+"].txt' USING PigStorage(' ');";
```

This approach does not scale to values greater than 9, as from 10 it starts to take up two characters instead of one. One potential solution would be splitting *x* into a single digit and use this to build the pig String.

```
int tens   = x/10;
int single = x%10;
if(tens>0)
    pigString += "TRAIN = LOAD 'user/hdp/input/custom/Fold1/train[0-"+tens+"][0-+"single"+.txt' USING PigStorage(' ');";
else
    pigString += "TRAIN = LOAD 'user/hdp/input/custom/Fold1/train[0-"+single+"].txt' USING PigStorage(' ');";
```

This solutions however has two problems.

1. When *x>9* train 0 to 9 are not loaded because the glob matches the numbers 00, 01 and 02 instead of the single digit versions 0, 1 and 2. I did not see any support in Hadoop globs however for matching the first [0-"+tens+"] part zero or one time (like with ? in regular expressions).
2. When single is any value smaller than 9, the data files are also only loaded up to this value for all values lower than tens. Lets say x = 24, than the code above only load 10-14, but not 15-19. I did not see anything in the Hadoop glob documentation however to make the second matched digit dependend on the first matched didit.

Does anyone know any generic solution to load my range of data files up to any value of *x*? I don't know if I'm at the right track using glob's, so any other non-glob solution would also be very much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are forming the pigString in JAVA, why dont you use x.toString() to form the file name as below: 
    "/user/hdp/input/custom/Fold1/train" + x + ".txt"?

Surround this with for loop running from 0 to x.

Comment: Because then I would have x LOAD-statements that each load one train file, while I need 1 LOAD-statement that loads x train files at once

Comment: Oh, got it. I think you are struggling with creating regex for 2 digit number (including 0 to 9). Does this help: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html?

Comment: Yes, that document described exactly the same problem that I am experiencing, but for the case of regular expressions. However, I am not so sure Pig supports regular expressions for the case of loading files (the only reference of usage of regular expressions in Pig is in the case of filter functions: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch05.html#filter). Simple globbing is supported in Pig, but I am not so sure if it is possible to solve this issue purely with globbing.

Comment: got it. I don't see a way to create complex regex using globs.
By the way, thanks for writing the neat question with code sample.

Comment: You're welcome :). I also doubt there is a glob-based solution. I can imagine however that I am not the only one with the need to load a range of numbered files with Pig (e.g. think of analysis of numbered log-files), so I expect that there is something within Pig that supports loading ranges of files that I am currently missing.

Comment: If possible, dump the necessary files in 1 directory from your java code and let Pig load the new directory as a whole.

Comment: Unfortunately, moving around the data is not something I can do prior to every run. The train files are approx 5GB each, so this would result in a massive amount of data that needs moving around.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can create symlinks to these selected files and store the symlinks in a directory; then read this dir from pig.

Comment: I solved a similar problem quite recently. I used Python and mako to generate a pig script. To get a list of files I used `fs -ls`. Since you are getting code to write code why not just load all the files separately and do a union?

Comment: Please help on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38706919/funtion-to-convert-specific-date-range-to-hdfs-glob-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at hadoop [glob](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29) signature, and it seems like it should be easy to do than what we thought initially.

Create a comma separated string of all the numbers that you are interested in and call it expectedNumber. e.g. expectedNumbers = "0,1,2,3,4,5" and then use it as below:

```
pigString += "TRAIN = LOAD 'user/hdp/input/custom/Fold1/train" + {expectedNumbers} +".txt' USING PigStorage(' ');";
```

Hope this helps.